# Android Emulator (Can't bind to local 8601 and 8627 for debugger)

Tags: android

I recently started android development. With my Hello world app,it is running OK and gives accurate output. emulator but showing warning "cant bind to local 8627 for debugger" and "cant bind to local 8601 for debugger"  .
and does not show the intellisense and all java files are red.

[image]

Please help for to figure out .Thank you in advance

[[image][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/noU6C.png)

Comment: Hi Muhammad, welcome to SO! Posting images of code is not acceptable here on SO, instead you will need to copy your code into your question and format it correctly. It may also be worthwhile reading through these if you haven't already: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

It is likely that the port is occupied,8601 or 8627. Two methods:

- Open the Task Manager , find it and kill it.
- Add this in your hosts file:  `127.0.0.1`  localhost

  hosts file can be found from:

  windows: C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts

  linux: /etc/hosts

Comment: how can i find from task manager ?
In 2nd method hosts file already contain 127.0.0.1

Comment: File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart... -> Select Invalidate and Restart
its working

Comment: Congratulation , File ->Invalidate ..... is also my method to resolve problem which I don't know how to resolve , and sometimes I will reboot system.